# Express.js. Route level middleware is not getting called

Tags: typescript, express, express-router

I have an API made with Express.js and TypeScript. It works completely fine except that middleware is not getting called - routing request passed successfully to the handler, but middleware is not getting involved at all.

Here is how routes are defined.

```
class TagsRoute implements Routes {
    public path = '/tags';
    public router = Router();
    public tagsController = new TagsController();

    constructor() {
        this.initializeRoutes();
    }

    private initializeRoutes() {
        this.router.get(`${this.path}`, this.tagsController.getTagPosts);
        this.router.get(`${this.path}/read`, this.tagsController.getTags);
        this.router.post(`${this.path}`, authMiddleware, this.tagsController.addTag);
        this.router.delete(`${this.path}`, authMiddleware, this.tagsController.deleteTag);
        this.router.put(`${this.path}`, authMiddleware, this.tagsController.editTag);
    }
}

export default TagsRoute;
```

Here is how middleware is defined:

```
const authMiddleware = (error: HttpException, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
    try {
        if (
            req.headers.authorization &&
            req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer'
        ) {
            const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

            admin.initializeApp({
                credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
            });

            getAuth()
                .verifyIdToken(token)
                .then((decodedToken) => {
                    if (!decodedToken || decodedToken.exp < Date.now()) {
                        res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
                    }
                    next()
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    res.status(401).json({message: "Invalid token"});
                });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};

export default authMiddleware;
```

Comment: How are you testing to see the middleware function was not invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of its first argument, `authMiddleware` is [error-handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use), which is called only if an error has occurred before and propagated with `next(error)`.

But looking at the code of `authMiddleware`, it seems that you do not need the `error` argument at all. So you should simply omit it:

```js
const authMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
 ...
};
```